# php / paypal: How to set receiver email?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I have multiple e-mail addresses registered with my paypal account. This way I can give regional customers a local paypal email dedicated to the local site.
For example paypal@englishname.com and paypal@germanname.de.

But how can I set the receiver (payee) email using the php rest api?

I tried:

```
$transaction->setEmail('paypal@germanname.de');
```

But I get the error message:
    PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method

I found the correct API call:
https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/lib/PayPal/Api/Payee.php
But I can't get it to work.

Everything else is working so far. I am following this example: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the example at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php.

You need to create the $payee object

```
$payee = new Api\Payee();
$payee->setEmail("payee@example.com");
```

Then when creating the $transaction object, call the 'setPayee' method, using $payee from above as the parameter.

```
$transaction = new Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
            ->setItemList($itemList)
            ->setDescription("Payment description")
            ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid())
            ->setPayee($payee);
```

Comment: And for billing / recurrent payment?